# WooCommerce REST API for guest users

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, woocommerce, codeigniter-3

I want to get category list, product list and add to cart without login from my WooCommerce store.

As per [WooCommerce API](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/), we have to generate **Consumer Key** and **Consumer Secret** before accessing any API. As per my understanding Consumer Key and Consumer Secret is not available.

Please let me know how can I get data from my WooCommerce store?

Thanks.

Comment: Key and secret are only not available if you are trying to access a shop that is not yours.

Comment: That's fine without key and secret no one can access. 

But is it possible that single key and secret for all customer?
Without selection of customer could i generate key and secret ?

Comment: Yes, the key and secret are generated independent of customers. You can generate multiple pairs, each with different rights for the users of those key. Multiple users can use the same key. Think carefully about how you want to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the API without key and secret. Otherwise you would be able to access any shop you like.

You can generate them in the settings of your WooCommerce Shop:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/