# Any woocommerce REST API for guest account?

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

Woocommerce provides an API [here](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/) which in order to use it, you have to provide a consumer key and consumer secret with a relevant authorization schema. What I fail to grasp is that, shouldn't be there an API for unauthorized / guest users ? I mean, I just want to create a display page (frontend) of available products, but without the need of generating CK/CS. Also looking in a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54232591/woocommerce-rest-api-for-guest-users)
it seems that you cannot avoid using the keys. But a second question comes up. The frontend is not supposed to use the keys, because then the e-shop becomes exposed to the client. So, even by generating these keys in order to access woocommerce api, how am I supposed to correctly use them ? Please help me understand the flow.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR;**

Do **NOT** use CK/CS in front end. It's only for use in a secure backend. The keys can be used to read/write anything from products to, orders to all customer related information.

Based on you questions, I suspect APIs might not be the best way to do what you're intending to do. If you do need APIs, chances are, you have two backend servers communicating with each other. APIs are usually meant for use by other applications. For example, a lot of Point of Sale systems utilize this WooCommerce API. You might want to look into [extending the WooCommerce plugin](https://woocommerce.com/documentation/woocommerce-codex/extending/) itself and creating end points to get the information or perform actions you need.

If you are not familiar with secure Authenticated APIs, I would highly suggest you familiarize yourself with them as failure to secure the website can result in huge financial losses to sensitive personal information leakage of the site users since WooCommerce APIs, at the time of this writing, only allows you to set read or write permissions with full access to everything.

With that in mind I will attempt to answer all of your questions one by one and give an idea of how you should use it.

**To Answer your questions**

> What I fail to grasp is that, shouldn't be there an API for
> unauthorized / guest users ? I mean, I just want to create a display
> page (frontend) of available products, but without the need of
> generating CK/CS

I'm guessing your misconception is that you need to use separate keys for each user. **API keys are not meant to give access for front-end users**. The API keys generated by the WooCommerece plugin gives full read/write access to any user to view/modify any information including that of other customers. Its meant for admins. If you check the official WooCommerce API reference for [retrieving a customer](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#retrieve-a-customer) you'll notice that you get to provide an id here. And if you check the response it shows everything from addresses to contact information.

> The frontend is not supposed to use the keys, because then the e-shop
> becomes exposed to the client. So, even by generating these keys in
> order to access woocommerce api, how am I supposed to correctly use
> them ?

Its quite simple actually. You just need to get between the communication between the front-end users and the WooCommerce API. If the users needs to be provided information from the WooCommerce end point, you need to get it for them using the CK/CS.

This way, you confirm what information is allowed to view/modify by whom, and the user does not need to be authenticated.

```
WooCommerce Endpoints <---> Your secure backend service/middleware/controller <---> front-end user
```

One thing to note though, is that you need to be careful about the parameters a front-end user is able to change in the request to your server end-point that is consuming the WooCommerce API key. A customer should not be able to change the id that is requesting their info for example. Id should be retrieved from the backend from the secure authentication information coming from the front-end.